# Need a design pattern for getting only specific features common across classes

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, typescript, design-patterns

I have to choose a design pattern for the following scenario. Though I will be implementing it in Typescript, but I need to make it generic in order to implement it across languages.

Problem statement is that - Let's say I have functionalities `driveInAir()`, `driveOnRoad()`, `driveOnWater()` and some more.

Now I have classes which contains only subset or all of these features. For example - a flying car might have driveOnRoad and driveInAir, while a ship might have just driveOnWater. However the definition of each of these functionalities are common across classes and hence I do not want to redefine them.

Also a Ship should not be able to access driveOnRoad functionality. I am developing this in Typescript, but the design pattern chosen should be also extendable in other languages such as python, Java etc.

One of the ideal candidate for this is mixins which is another form of multiple inheritance where I define a class containing just one function defining a functionality. And class Ship or FlyingCar extends the classes which it needs. But mixins/multiple inheritance are not supported across the languages, so it's not something I am a big fan of. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking something in the lines of this:

```
class Drive {
    public driveInAir(vehicle: Vehicle): void {
        console.log('Your ' + vehicle.Name + ' is flying!');
    }
    public driveOnRoad(vehicle: Vehicle): void {
        console.log('Your ' + vehicle.Name + ' is driving on a road.');
    }
    public driveOnWater(vehicle: Vehicle): void {
        console.log('Your ' + vehicle.Name + ' is motorboating!');
    }
}

class Vehicle {
    public Name: string;
}

class AirRoadVehicle extends Vehicle {
    private _drive: Drive = new Drive();

    driveInAir(): void {
        this._drive.driveInAir(this);
    }
    driveOnRoad(): void {
        this._drive.driveOnRoad(this);
    }
}

class WaterVehicle extends Vehicle {
    private _drive: Drive = new Drive();

    driveOnWater(): void {
        this._drive.driveOnWater(this);
    }
}

class FlyingCar extends AirRoadVehicle {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.Name = 'Flying car';
    }

    goCrazy(): void {
        this.driveOnRoad();
        this.driveOnRoad();
        this.driveInAir();
    }
}

class Boat extends WaterVehicle {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.Name = 'Boat';
    }

    tryTakingTheHighroad(): void {
        this.driveOnRoad(); //Property 'driveOnRoad' does not exist on type 'Boat'.
    }
}
```

Though you will need a few middle-classes to handle all cases.

You can try this out [Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Drive%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20driveInAir(vehicle%3A%20Vehicle)%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('Your%20'%20%2B%20vehicle.Name%20%2B%20'%20is%20flying!')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20driveOnRoad(vehicle%3A%20Vehicle)%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('Your%20'%20%2B%20vehicle.Name%20%2B%20'%20is%20driving%20on%20a%20road.')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20driveOnWater(vehicle%3A%20Vehicle)%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('Your%20'%20%2B%20vehicle.Name%20%2B%20'%20is%20motorboating!')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Vehicle%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20Name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20AirRoadVehicle%20extends%20Vehicle%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20_drive%3A%20Drive%20%3D%20new%20Drive()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20driveInAir()%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._drive.driveInAir(this)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20driveOnRoad()%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._drive.driveOnRoad(this)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20WaterVehicle%20extends%20Vehicle%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20_drive%3A%20Drive%20%3D%20new%20Drive()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20driveOnWater()%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._drive.driveOnWater(this)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20FlyingCar%20extends%20AirRoadVehicle%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.Name%20%3D%20'Flying%20car'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20goCrazy()%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.driveOnRoad()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.driveOnRoad()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.driveInAir()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Boat%20extends%20WaterVehicle%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.Name%20%3D%20'Boat'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20tryTakingTheHighroad()%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.driveOnRoad()%3B%20%2F%2FProperty%20'driveOnRoad'%20does%20not%20exist%20on%20type%20'Boat'.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20flyingCar%20%3D%20new%20FlyingCar()%3B%0D%0AflyingCar.goCrazy()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20boat%20%3D%20new%20Boat()%3B%0D%0Aboat.tryTakingTheHighroad()%3B%20%2F%2FUncaught%20TypeError%3A%20this.driveOnRoad%20is%20not%20a%20function) (check console for output when running).

Comment: This looks like a good candidate as far as design is considered. Mixins basically do that same thing in typescipt or for that matter any other language(just that you mix the functionalities from different classes). You define the classes, implement the functionalities and the derived class override their methods with the ones defined in parent class. But this looks more generic. Than you so much!

Comment: @Rishabh No problem, please upvote and mark as answer if this helped you!